# Concept needed for up/down voting using AJAX and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, voting-system

I'm working on an app that has up and down voting similar to StackExchange.

I want to be able to have the following

1. user clicks up vote, and a record in the vote table gets populated with 1
2. user clicks up vote again and the record is deleted

^^ same thing happens with down votes

or

1. user clicks up vote, and a record in the vote table gets populated with 1
2. user clicks down vote instead, and the original record is deleted, and a new record is added with -1

My table looks like this

```
USE [MyProject]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EventVotes]    Script Date: 02/21/2011 15:16:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventVotes](
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EventID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Vote] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VoteDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EventVotes_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserID] ASC,
    [EventID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventVotes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventVotes_Events] FOREIGN KEY([EventID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Events] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventVotes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventVotes_Events]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventVotes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventVotes_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventVotes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventVotes_Users]
GO
```

I need a good concept in how to implement this. Do I call a `VoteController` Action and send it two params? `bool isUpDown` and `int Vote`

```
If isUpDown Then
    MyRepository.Delete(EventID, UserID) 
    MyRepository.SubmitChanges()
End If

MyRepository.Insert(EventID, UserID, Vote)
MyRepository.SubmitChanges()
```

I don't know if there are any holes in this logic, or if there is a better way to achieve this. The plan is to do it all via AJAX.

Also, should the view have two forms (one for UP and one for DOWN), or should I try an manage more with jQuery? I'm just not sure how to approach this particular problem.

Comment: What you asking?  Forms or ajax is totally up to you and wouldn't have an effect on how functional it is.

Comment: I'm asking A) is the logic sound, an B) is there any advantage to using forms?

Comment: did you take a look at the stack overflow creative commons data dump? Hanselman created an EF model from it. You should just base your DB on Stack's DB schema. That's what i'll be doing when i also have to put voting into our system.

Comment: Oh, didn't know this existed. Where might we find this gem?

Comment: @RPM1984 - do you know where I can find the data dump and Hanselman's EF model?

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - here you go: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement it with jQuery and one Action like with two arguments bool upDown and int EventID.
Your action can return a JSON with the result (accept or reject depending on if the user has voted previously) and the current votes for that event.